# unwanted row indent css

Tags: html, css

I have an unwanted space in my lists. The code is below but I have 3 column lists of about 8 rows, but the last rows first list item is causing an unwanted space. Almost looks like it just entirely moves over to the next column with nothing in its place. Not sure why. Other than that last row the lists are working fine. Any help?

html

```
<div id="museums" class="clearfix">

        <div class="entry">
            <p>The Art Institute of Chicago</p>
            <p>Art</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/2/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/2" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/2">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>The Field Museum</p>
            <p>Natural History</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/3/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/3" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/3">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Museum of Contemporary Art</p>
            <p>Art</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/4/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/4" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/4">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Museum of Science and Industry</p>
            <p>Science and Technology</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/5/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/5" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/5">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Adler Planetarium</p>
            <p>Universe</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/6/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/6" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/6">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>The Chicago History Museum</p>
            <p>History</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/7/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/7" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/7">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Museum of Broadcast Communications</p>
            <p>Radio and Television</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/8/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/8" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/8">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>The Shedd Aquarium</p>
            <p>Marine Life</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/9/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/9" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/9">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>The Notebaert Nature Museum</p>
            <p>Nature</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/10/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/10" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/10">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>DuSable Museum of African American History</p>
            <p>African American History</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/11/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/11" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/11">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Frank Lloyd Wright Home and Studio</p>
            <p>Architecture</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/12/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/12" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/12">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>National Museum of Mexican Art</p>
            <p>Mexican Culture</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/13/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/13" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/13">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Jane Addams Hull House Museum</p>
            <p>Social Welfare </p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/14/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/14" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/14">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Abraham Lincoln Museum</p>
            <p>History</p>
            <p>Chicago , 
            Illinois</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/15/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/15" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/15">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Rebecca's Test Museum</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>St. Paul, 
            Minnesota</p><br />

            <div class="edit">
             <!--JH - allow only logged in users to see edit and delete links-->
                <a href="/museums/16/edit">Edit</a><br />
                <a href="/museums/16" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>

          <br />
                <a href="/museums/16">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

css

```
div.entry {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 30px 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;

}

div.entry p:first-child  {
    width: 290px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #E07951;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div.entry p:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 17px;
}

div.entry p {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.edit {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see your columns or rows there?  Can you give us a jsfiddle or other site with some example code?

Comment: Post the generated HTML and all CSS.

Comment: Made a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mQrnS/

Comment: Oh wow thanks. I am never used jsfiddle but I will start now. Can you see the issue? Looks fine there, but on my chrome screen. The last row "Jane Adams" is pushed over to the next column.

Comment: @Nerdysyntax see my answer. It's a common css float problem. There are a wide number of solutions, but there's a compromise that has to be made no matter which option chosen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@d_r_w very well explained the problem with floats.

You can try **`display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;`** on each of your blocks.
**[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/ssbMR/)**

Limitations:

- contrary to tables or (better) `display: table-cell;`, your blocks won't really be of same height. On white background, all is well and the problem with floats described by d_r_w is gone but if you add a background or a border around each box, you'll see that they each have the height of their content. You still can add a background shorter than any content, on the first 3 lines for example.
- mixing width in % and padding in px easily makes 3 div larger than 100% for many viewport widths. :( You'd better use only % (partially done in the fiddle)
- `inline-block` will output whitespace as a space, as for any whitespace between, say, two `span`. If you don't want these ~4 px (3*33.33% + 3* 4px > 100% width and *badaboom*, see above), you've to add an HTML comment between each div `</div><!-- nothing --><div>` or output in your template NO whitespace, nil, nada (and add a comment for your colleagues on why it's done like that).

Other solution that will request extra div for each line/row: `display: table; /* and table-row and table-cell */`
Compatibility: IE8+, and back to "inline-block" for IE6/7 (that is, `display: inline; zoom: 1;` equals inline-block on those old browsers)

Comment: I have to say this is the winning answer. Adding a height gave me weird padding on the bottom of each list but this trick give me equal spacing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the way floating elements work. It orders the elements left-to-right based on exactly the order you have them in the HTML, but the element on the second to last row is actually longer than the other elements on the right, so when the next row occurs, it will place the following elements in the most reasonable (to the browser) location, which is directly to the right underneath the immediate row. This results in the very last item appearing as if it's a new row.

Visually speaking, this is occurring:

```
+-+-+-+
|A|B|C|
+-+-+-+
|D|E|F|
| +-+-+
+-+G|H|
|I+-+-+
+-+
```

Short of using `min-height` to have a guaranteed length in your typical browsing environment, or perhaps even `table`s (ew!), there's not a good way to solve for this in CSS.

There is, however, a javascript solution. It's a jQuery plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). I recommend it for this type of situation.

It's also worth noting that Masonry helps things stay consistent for column displays no matter how many columns are possible (mobile environments, wide screen monitors, etc.).

Comment: Wow that's exactly what is it looks like. I tried masonry but for some  reason masonry.js doesn't work with rails 3.1.3. Well it kinda does, but not in all browsers and resizing kills it. I hope there is a css solution.

Comment: Strange, resizing support is an option by default. Do you have new elements which appear on the page dynamically? There's support for triggering the reorganization, but it does have to be bound to whichever event you're performing (such as adding an item to your collection).

Comment: That I don't not know. I got it to work without rails and when I used the same script $('#museums').masonry({ itemSelector: '.entry' });, it works. But when I resize, there is just one column list and this happens onload with other browsers.

Comment: It may be due to a calculation it's performing based on your parent container's attributes derived from the rest of your css file (whatever `.clearfix` exhibits) on top of the relative width (30%) of your inner `.entry` elements. I cannot say for certain though without the full CSS. Admittedly, the simpler solution would probably prove to work just as well, but if you get the edge case of a place requiring a lot of text, you'll find yourself in the original boat all over again.

Comment: Yea this is for a ruby on rails class at my school. I am ahead of schedule and wanted to add some jQuery. I didn't think about clearfix. I forgot I had that in my code. I might revisit that later. Masonry is awesome for the not so math guys like me.

Answer (score 1):

it is float issue.

the div that contains "DuSable Museum of African American History" has a bigger height than other divs. so it pushes the divs from next row.

2 things we can do

1) set a fixed height for each div 
eg: add `hegiht: 300px;` or sth like that to div.entry

2) if fixed height is not possible, then add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after every 3rd div in html markup.

Comment: The downside to (1) is that different font sizes on a person's default browser settings could seriously bork the way the elements are displayed. The only downside to (2) is it doesn't help when the screen size shrinks. If you have a mobile device and only room for two columns, this will still face the row mismatch issue.

Comment: Wow all that just to have floating horizontal lists. Sucks flash is ending, this never was a problem there lol.

Comment: Added a height and it looks fine, but I worry about the downsides.